# Python spider show row elements of data frame while write empty line on file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is essentially the main part of the code concerning the problem:

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv('~/Dropbox/data/anand/surface/scan/7/relaxed/dos/DOSCAR',skiprows=5, names=['energy','su' , 'sd','pu' ,'pd' ,'du' ,'dd' ],delimiter='\s+',engine='python')

#Remove the two lines but I want to keep the 1st one only 
#it is why I change the value to 1 () instead of being 1!
df1.iat[0,1]=1
df=df1[df1.su != enmin ]
df=df1[df1.energy != enmin ]
df1=None
df.to_csv(r'~/df', header=None, index=None, sep=' ',mode='a')
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

and then I just access some values of df through df.iat[,]

Actually the line number 6000 corresponds to the line that I wanted to keep and which should be located at the beginning of the text. It is like misplacing/inverting the order.

I have tried to open it also with vim but same issue, and I am sure the dataframe window on python is the correct one. Please note that gedit and other tex editor starts with line number 1 while dataframe start with zero.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The mistake came from the fact the second dropping operation of df does not take into account the first one since you a rewriting a again a completely new dataframe from df1 and not from the previous df.